# Google Map Error 602

Tags: html

The listed code has been working for 3 years. All of a sudden I am starting to get error message "No corresponding geographic location could be found for one of the specified addresses. This may be due to the fact that the address is relatively new, or it may be incorrect" Error code 602.
Hope you can help.
Here is the code.

```
<style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        margin: 2px;
      }
      table.directions th {
 background-color:#EEEEEE;
      }

      img {
        color: #000000;
      }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var gdir;
    var geocoder = null;
    var addressMarker;
 var toaddress = "844 Kinderkamack Rd, River Edge, NJ 07661";
    function initialize() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        gdir = new GDirections(map, document.getElementById("directions"));
        GEvent.addListener(gdir, "load", onGDirectionsLoad);
        GEvent.addListener(gdir, "error", handleErrors);

        setDirections("Eddison, NJ 08817", toaddress, "en_US");
      }
    }

    function setDirections(fromAddress, toAddress, locale) {
      gdir.load("from: " + fromAddress + " to: " + toAddress,
                { "locale": locale });
    }

    function handleErrors(){
    if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS)
      alert("No corresponding geographic location could be found for one of the specified addresses. This may be due to the fact that the address is relatively new, or it may be incorrect.\nError code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);
    else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_SERVER_ERROR)
      alert("A geocoding or directions request could not be successfully processed, yet the exact reason for the failure is not known.\n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);

    else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_MISSING_QUERY)
      alert("The HTTP q parameter was either missing or had no value. For geocoder requests, this means that an empty address was specified as input. For directions requests, this means that no query was specified in the input.\n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);

 //   else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_UNAVAILABLE_ADDRESS)  <--- Doc bug... this is either not defined, or Doc is wrong
 //     alert("The geocode for the given address or the route for the given directions query cannot be returned due to legal or contractual reasons.\n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);

    else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_BAD_KEY)
      alert("The given key is either invalid or does not match the domain for which it was given. \n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);

    else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_BAD_REQUEST)
      alert("A directions request could not be successfully parsed.\n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);

    else alert("An unknown error occurred.");

 }

 function onGDirectionsLoad(){
      // Use this function to access information about the latest load()
      // results.

      // e.g.
      // document.getElementById("getStatus").innerHTML = gdir.getStatus().code;
   // and yada yada yada...
 }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">

<h2 align="center">Driving Directions to Bhatia Nurseries</h2>

<form action="#"
onsubmit="setDirections(this.from.value, toaddress, this.locale.value); return false">
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <th align="right">From:&nbsp;</th>
      <td><input type="text" size="25" id="fromAddress" name="from"
      value="Enter Your Address Here" /></td>
<!---<td align="right"><input type="text" size="25" id="toAddress" name="to"
     value="Kinderkamack Rd, River Edge, NJ" /></td></tr> -->
      <th>Language:&nbsp;</th>
      <td><select id="locale" name="locale" size="1">
        <option value="en" selected>English</option>
        <option value="fr">French</option>
        <option value="de">German</option>
        <option value="ja">Japanese</option>
        <option value="es">Spanish</option>
      </select> <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Get Directions!" /> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<p align="center">Double click on the map to zoom in, Click and drag to move map in window 
<br/></p>

<table class="directions">
  <tr>
    <th>Formatted Directions</th>
    <th>Map</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div id="directions" style="width: 275px"></div></td>
    <td valign="top"><div id="map_canvas" style="width: 410px; height: 400px"></div><p><br>
    <a href="index.html" target="_top">Bhatia Nurseries Home</a> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled `Edison`.

Comment: After correcting Eddison To Edison, "Unterminated String Constant on line 49" appear as error.

Comment: I was using a corrupted editor, thus the problems and syntax errors. Sorry if I caused any problems and thanks for your kind response.

Answer (score 2):

@SLaks already answered the issue at hand.

For reference, Google's error codes can be found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GGeoStatusCode):

> ```
> G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS = 602
> ```
>
> No corresponding geographic location could be found for the specified address. This may be due to the fact that the address is relatively new, or it may be incorrect.